# How can I use SQL Server bulk insert in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm a beginner in asp.net and  write a web application. I have 100 million records in my server in a `.csv` file, and I write this query in SQL Server to import all that data:

```
BULK INSERT BpartyTEMP
FROM 'D:\bparty2.csv'
WITH(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   CODEPAGE = '1256'
);
```

But I want write that query directly in asp.net c# code, how can I write that? Thanks.

Comment: You just use your normal `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` ADO.NET components, and use this SQL as the `CommandText` for your command. Easy peasy....

Comment: thanks my friend to answer my problem,please post your solution,@marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use your normal `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` ADO.NET components, and use this SQL as the `CommandText` for your command.

```
string bulkInsertQuery = "(your BULK INSERT statement here)";

using (SqlConnnection con = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(bulkInsertQuery, con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```